# Spawning bots using array maybe

Tags: java

Im quite unsure how to go about this but I'll do my best.

I have a few relevant classes for listing the images, another for the bots which tells them what to do and another for painting to the screen. What I'm having trouble with is getting a bot to duplicate itself and then use the same code as the original when ..say space is pressed.

Java is still quite new to me.

I'm using this to state images:

```
Bot = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/botDown.gif")).getImage();
```

The code manipulating the bot to do stuff is just a bunch of if statements changing `botx` and `boty` around. I'm guessing that by using an array to assign more bots when space is pressed is the way to go. Otherwise, the way I would do it is code more bots myself copy and pasting all the IFs and then set space to increment a value by 1 and assign each bot accordingly (The bad way). Hope that helps explain.

Any advice is appreciated Thanks!

added example of bot class code:

```
if (Botx < Botx2 + 50 && Botx > Botx2 && Boty > Boty2 - 50
        && Boty < Boty2 + 50) {
    Botx = Botx + 2;
}
if (Botx > Botx2 - 50 && Botx < Botx2 && Boty < Boty2 + 50
        && Boty > Boty2 - 50) {
    Botx = Botx - 2;
}
if (Boty > Boty2 && Boty < Boty2 + 50 && Botx < Botx2 + 50
        && Botx > Botx2 - 50) {
    Boty = Boty + 2;
}
if (Boty < Boty2 && Boty > Boty2 - 50 && Botx < Botx2 + 50
        && Botx > Botx2 - 50) {
    Boty = Boty - 2;
}
//Anti Collision push BOT2
if (Botx2 < Botx + 50 && Botx2 > Botx && Boty2 > Boty - 50
        && Boty2 < Boty + 50) {
    Botx2 = Botx2 + 2;
}
if (Botx2 > Botx - 50 && Botx2 < Botx && Boty2 < Boty + 50
        && Boty2 > Boty - 50) {
    Botx2 = Botx2 - 2;
}
if (Boty2 > Boty && Boty2 < Boty + 50 && Botx2 < Botx + 50
        && Botx2 > Botx - 50) {
    Boty2 = Boty2 + 2;
}
if (Boty2 < Boty && Boty2 > Boty - 50 && Botx2 < Botx + 50
        && Botx2 > Botx - 50) {
    Boty2 = Boty2 - 2;
}
```

Comment: What are the conditions in the if statements?

Comment: Hmm they are only telling the bot to move away if they get too close to each other. I'm using Bot1 and Bot2 to assign new bots manually.

Comment: I've updated the question to explain better. I don't normally ask questions. I spend hours trying to work it out myself haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle any number of bots:

```
for(Bot bot : botArray) {
    for(Bot bot2 : botArray) {
        if(!bot.equals(bot2) {
            // Push bot around (not bot2 since it will be handled in another iteration)
        }
    }
}
```

But depending on the conditions, a bot could collides with a second bot while trying to avoid a third bot.

By the way, I think your code could be improved by using `Math.abs(x - x2)`